# How to calculate current value on object based on previous conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for optimization for the following.

I have an object that has a few properties. For simplicity i will show the only 2 that matter in this scenario.

```
 public class DomainData
 {
   public long Id{ get; set; }
   public long SoldTickets { get; set; }
 }
```

I make a call to my db and get a list of the above object:

```
 var databaseData = _iOvervatchManager.GetDomainData(id);// gets date from db

 var model = new List<DomainModel>();
```

Now I need to calculate how many tickets have been sold between list items.

> current = current - previous

I do the calculation with the following code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= databaseData.Count() -1; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            long ticket = databaseData[i].SoldTickets- databaseData[i - 1].SoldTickets;
            model.Add(new DomainModel 
                { 
                         DomainId = databaseData[i].DomainId ,
                         SoldTicketsLastUpdate = ticket
               });
        }
    }
```

And now set the value on the original object.

```
    for(int i= 0; i< databaseData.Count(); i++)
    {
        if(databaseData[i].Id == model[i].DomainId )
           databaseData[i].SoldTickets = model[i].SoldTicketsLastUpdate;
    }
```

I consider this an awful way of accomplishing this since I recon I can do this in the first loop but I can't figure out how.

my first attempt was :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= databaseData.Count() -1; i++)
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
       databaseData[i].SoldTickets 
                        = databaseData[i].SoldTickets - databaseData[i - 1].SoldTickets;
    }
}
```

But this was wrong since i change the object value and when I come to the next increment the previous value has been modified so the current for that loop increment gets a wrong calculation.

How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that no new data will be added after this runs (!!), execute the for-loop backwards:

```
for (int i = databaseData.Count() - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    databaseData[i].SoldTickets = databaseData[i].SoldTickets - databaseData[i - 1].SoldTickets;
}
```

And because the loop only runs for `i > 0`, the check for `i != 0` is unneeded.

Comment: Thank you! never considered doing this